# How to use hyphen/dash in a url?

Tags: php, yii2

I have this button in the **_form.php** file.

```
'buttons' => [
    'replace' => function($url, $model) {
        return Html::a(
            'Replace',
            [
                '/european-countries/replace',
                'countryIdReplacement' => '123' // Problem here.
            ]
        );
    },
],
```

My controller:

```
public function actionReplace($countryIdReplacement) {
    // My code.
}
```

The URL is:

http://my-site/european-countries/replace?countryIdReplacement=123

I want to use this variable format:

http://my-site/european-countries/replace?country-id-replacement=123

But PHP doesn't allow to use that format. This is not allowed:

```
actionReplace($country-id-replacement)
```

Comment: Did you tried `'country-id-replacement' => '123'`?

Comment: Yes, but the controller doesn't allow actionReplace($country-id-replacement).

Comment: You should use `actionReplace(${'country-id-replacement'})` or `Yii::$app->request->get('country-id-replacement')`.